# How can I use subqueries in sequelize.js?

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to change the subquery below to the sequelize code.
Could you let me know if there's a way to change to the form below

```
select 
product_seq
, product_type_code
, (select  DETAIL_KOREAN_NAME from CODE_DETAIL where code_id = 'A0001' and detail_code_id =  product_type_code) as product_type
from land.PRODUCT;
```

For example

```
models.Product.findAll({
        attributes: ['newColumn']........
    }).then((data)=>{
        res.json(data)
    })
```

Comment: **Must** you use a subuery?  Sequelize doesn't do subqueries to well, but your query could be a regular join.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good example to start from.

```
models.Product.findAll({
      attributes: ['product_type_code']
      include: [
        {
          model: models.CODE_DETAIL,
          where: { 
            code_id: { [Op.eq]: 'A0001' },
            detail_code_id =  { [Op.eq]: Sequelize.col('product_type_code') }
          }
          attributes: [ ['DETAIL_KOREAN_NAME', 'product_type'] ]
        }]
    });
```

Note that a better way would be to build the models relations before hand, like:

```
models.Product.hasMany(models.CODE_DETAIL, { foreignKey: 'detail_code_id', sourceKey: 'product_type_code' });
```

So the query could then look like:

```
models.Product.findAll({
      attributes: ['product_type_code']
      include: [
        {
          model: models.CODE_DETAIL,
          where: { 
            code_id: { [Op.eq]: 'A0001' }
          }
          attributes: [ ['DETAIL_KOREAN_NAME', 'product_type'] ]
        }]
    });
```